# how to fix 404 warnings for images during karma unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, http-status-code-404, karma-runner

I'm unit testing one of my directives (angularjs) using grunt/karma/phantomjs/jasmine. My tests run fine

```
describe('bar foo', function () {
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        elm = angular.element('<img bar-foo src="img1.png"/>');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile(elm)();
        scope.$digest();
    }));
    ....
});
```

but I do get these 404s

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /img1.png
WARN [web-server]: 404: /img2.png
...
```

Although they do nothing, they do add noise to the log output. Is there a way to fix this ? (without changing karma's logLevel of course, because I do want to see them)

Comment: Does it persist in a different browser? I know there are some known issues with 404 errors for these types of calls in FF.

Comment: it has to be phantomjs. I checked Chrome which shows the 404 too. Note that they are warnings, not errors!

Comment: Does using ng-src help?

Comment: nice try, but has the same result

Answer (score 111, accepted):

That is because you need to configurate karma to load then serve them when requested ;)

In your karma.conf.js file you should already have defined files and/or patterns like :

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files : [
  {pattern: 'app/lib/angular.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
  {pattern: 'app/lib/angular-*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
  {pattern: 'app/lib/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
  {pattern: 'app/js/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
  // add the line below with the correct path pattern for your case
  {pattern: 'path/to/**/*.png', watched: false, included: false, served: true},
  // important: notice that "included" must be false to avoid errors
  // otherwise Karma will include them as scripts
  {pattern: 'test/lib/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
  {pattern: 'test/unit/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
],

// list of files to exclude
exclude: [

],

// ...
```

You can have a look [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/files.html) for more info :)

**EDIT :** If you use a nodejs web-server to run your app, you can add this to karma.conf.js :

```
proxies: {
  '/path/to/img/': 'http://localhost:8000/path/to/img/'
},
```

**EDIT2 :** If you don't use or want to use another server you can define a local proxy but as Karma doesn't provide access to port in use, dynamically, if karma starts on another port than 9876 (default), you will still get those annoying 404...

```
proxies =  {
  '/images/': '/base/images/'
};
```

Related issue : https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/872

Comment: In my case these images do not exist. The solution you provide assumes the files exist, right ?

Comment: Yes of course! I think I misunderstood, it makes sense to have 404 errors for non-existing files, right? You would like to hide warnings related to images? Without changing the log level, I see no solution, moreover, that would hide other warnings, which would be risky. Why not create empty .png files in "test/img" folder for example? :)

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to work. What exactly is the relation between the url used in the HTML and the pattern in karma.conf.js ? For example if I have an image in **test/assets/img.png**, what should be the url ?

Comment: My apologies, this solution should work but I kept getting 404 errors too. I believe this is related to a lack of implementation in Karma and I am surprised that we are the only one to get it.
I found a (bit hacky) way to get this to work but you will need to run another (web)server in parallel of Karma. I will edit my answer. ;)

Comment: If the `basePath` option isn't used, the images could also be served under the `absolute/` path

Comment: In response to EDIT2 if you run karma on a custom port you can avoid the 404s by linking to the full URI of the karma server: (assuming `port: 9999`)
```proxies =  {
  '/images/': 'http://localhost:9999/base/images/'
};```

Comment: Tip: make sure to include the forward slash in the proxies object:
`'/images/': '/base/images/'`. Omitting it was giving me a hard time...

Comment: I found that `'/images/': ''` is actually sufficient enough to suppress the warning, and doesn't require setting up files.

Answer (score 19):

The confusing piece of the puzzle for me was the 'base' virtual folder. If you don't know that needs to be included in the asset paths of your fixtures you will find it hard to debug.

As-per [the configuration documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/files.html)

> By default all assets are served at http://localhost:[PORT]/base/

Note: this may not be true for other versions - I'm on 0.12.14 and it worked for me but the 0.10 docs dont mention it.

After specifying the files pattern:

```
{ pattern: 'Test/images/*.gif', watched: false, included: false, served: true, nocache: false },
```

I could use this in my fixture:

```
<img src="base/Test/images/myimage.gif" />
```

And I didn't need the proxy at that point.

Comment: This is the clincher. The top answer explains this but very briefly - thanks for expanding.

Answer (score 10):

You can create generic middleware inside your karma.conf.js
- bit over the top but did the job for me

First define dummy 1px images (I've used base64):

```
const DUMMIES = {
  png: {
    base64: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkYPhfDwAChwGA60e6kgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
    type: 'image/png'
  },
  jpg: {
    base64: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAABAAEDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD3+iiigD//2Q==',
    type: 'image/jpeg'
  },
  gif: {
    base64: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAA=',
    type: 'image/gif'
  }
};
```

Then define middleware function:

```
function surpassImage404sMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  const imageExt = req.url.split('.').pop();
  const dummy = DUMMIES[imageExt];

  if (dummy) {
    // Table of files to ignore
    const imgPaths = ['/another-cat-image.png'];
    const isFakeImage = imgPaths.indexOf(req.url) !== -1;

    // URL to ignore
    const isCMSImage = req.url.indexOf('/cms/images/') !== -1;

    if (isFakeImage || isCMSImage) {
      const img = Buffer.from(dummy.base64, 'base64');
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': dummy.type,
        'Content-Length': img.length
      });
      return res.end(img);
    }
  }
  next();
}
```

Apply middleware in your karma conf

```
{
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    middleware: ['surpassImage404sMiddleware'],
    plugins: [
      ...
      {'middleware:surpassImage404sMiddleware': ['value', surpassImage404sMiddleware]}
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you ever make it into an actual package? I would love to just npm install this

Comment: If you want to suppress all image requests, just check `req.headers.accept` to see if it contains `image` and return 204 if it does.

Answer (score 9):

Based on @glepretre's answer, I've created an empty .png file and added this to the config to hide 404 warnings:

```
proxies: {
  '/img/generic.png': 'test/assets/img/generic.png'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Even though its an old thread, it took me a couple hours to actually get my image to actually be served from karma to eliminate the 404. The comments were just not thorough enough. I believe I can clarify the solution with this screenshot. Essentially the one thing that many comments were missing is the fact that the **proxy value must start with "/base"**, even though base is not in any of my folder pathing, nor is it in my requests.

*("base" without the forward slash resulted in karma returning a 400 BAD REQUEST)*

Now after running **ng test**, I can successfully serve "./src/assets/favicon.png" from the url: http://localhost:9876/test/dummy.png

In my project I am using the following npm package versions:

- karma v4.3.0
- jasmine-core v3.2.1
- karma-jasmine v1.1.2
- @angular/cli v8.3.5
- angular v8.2.7

[image: VSCode project structure with karma.conf.js assets locations]

Comment: This insight was particularly helpful for me to understand that there's a difference (from Karma's perspective) for serving files within the base area, and from outside the base area (which was ultimately my issue), which then led me to https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2703.  So, thank you for this clarification.

Answer (score 4):

To fix, in your `karma.conf.js` make sure to point to the served file with your proxies:

```
files: [
  { pattern: './src/img/fake.jpg', watched: false, included: false, served: true },
],
proxies: {
  '/image.jpg': '/base/src/img/fake.jpg',
  '/fake-avatar': '/base/src/img/fake.jpg',
  '/folder/0x500.jpg': '/base/src/img/fake.jpg',
  '/undefined': '/base/src/img/fake.jpg'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using fake URLs for your images in test, you can write a custom middleware function to return `200` for URLs that start with "$", taken from [Angular's own `karma.conf.js`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/59002e1649123922df3532f4be78c485a73c5bc1/test/karma.conf.js):

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    middleware: ['fake-url'],
    plugins: [
      // ...
      {
        'middleware:fake-url': [
          'factory',
          function () {
            // Middleware that avoids triggering 404s during tests that need to reference
            // image paths. Assumes that the image path will start with `/$`.
            // Credit: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/59002e1649123922df3532f4be78c485a73c5bc1/test/karma.conf.js
            return function (request, response, next) {
              if (request.url.indexOf('/$') === 0) {
                response.writeHead(200);
                return response.end();
              }

              next();
            };
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  });
}
```

**foo.spec.ts**

```
img.src = '/$/foo.jpg'; // No 404 warning! :-)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have root path somewhere in your configuration file you can also use something like this:

```
proxies: {
  '/bower_components/': config.root + '/client/bower_components/'
}
```