# Local path for html files

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I am running jasmine tests on Karma server.
On my tests I have to load a image and a json file test.

They depend on path. Which is the default path for Karma? I mean if i have a image in a directory inside my .js test files how can I reach that file?

I have tested `src="myDir/myImage.jpg"` but no sucess...

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/872 ? However, I would suggest using requireJS also because Karma does not deal well with fixtures...

Comment: @glepretre, yes! `/base/` saved me. I see you are on the thread also. You are welcome to post a answer, and I''l be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a nodejs web-server to run your app, you can add this to karma.conf.js :

```
proxies: {
  '/path/to/img/': 'http://localhost:8000/path/to/img/'
},
```

If you don't use or want to use another server you can define a local proxy but as Karma doesn't provide access to port in use, dynamically, if karma starts on another port than 9876 (default), you will still get a 404 error...

```
proxies =  {
  '/images': 'http://localhost:9876/base/images'
};
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21262098/3049002)

Related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/872) for more info ;)

I would also suggest using requireJS because Karma does not deal well with fixtures...

Comment: Don't worry about port, $.ajax to `/base/my-fixture.html` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
proxies =  {
  '/images': 'http://localhost:9876/base/images'
};
```

To avoid `404 error` if karma starts in in a different port, even after setting proxies, do the following:

1. Kill all the process using the port starting from 9876 (killing node.exe will do the trick)
2. Run you karma with `9876` port free now
3. Subsequent runs will be mapped automatically by karma to whatever port it launches