# Loading scripts defined in HTML

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a html file which has the list of scripts (modules,controllers,service)to be loaded in order.

When i run this html file through karma, am getting 404 error in all the script files.

Below is the Karma file

```
files: [
    'src/webapp/project/webclnt/index.html',
    'src/SampleService.js',
    'tests/TestModule.js',
    ],
```

Below is the error

```
  05 07 2016 14:07:41.746:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/webapp/project/Family.js
    05 07 2016 14:07:41.753:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/webapp/project/Person.js
```

Can you help on this

Comment: Please Check This link... Hope this will help you...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067710/how-to-fix-404-warnings-for-images-during-karma-unit-testing

Comment: Now i have resolved the error....but i couldn't mock any service in the module..always i get Declaration error

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify the html file in 'files' section. Instead, you should set your proxies accordingly to access the HTML.
proxies goes into the karma.conf.js itself as,

```
proxies:{
"src":"/base/src/"
}
```