# Gitlab CI running Angular Jasmine tests crashing without error

Tags: angular, jasmine, gitlab, karma-jasmine

Having just setup Gitlab CI to run the Jasmine tests in my Angular project, I found the pipeline would bomb out with very little indication of the cause.

All my tests would pass when run locally using `ng test` or locally in headless Chrome (having followed [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#configure-cli-for-ci-testing-in-chrome) and [another guide](https://hackernoon.com/ci-cd-with-angular-6-firebase-gitlab-5118ad469e4d) to set that up). However, the pipeline would get to around 13/90 tests and then disconnect.

Here's a sample of the debug output (with `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG` in *karma.conf.js*):

```
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.311 secs)
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.475 secs)
15 03 2019 00:09:46.911:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /assets/img/logo.png
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 11 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1.659 secs)
15 03 2019 00:09:47.738:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /media/img/showcase-image.jpg
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 12 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1.875 secs)
15 03 2019 00:09:48.312:DEBUG [HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Disconnected during run, waiting 2000ms for reconnecting.
15 03 2019 00:09:48.312:DEBUG [HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0)]: EXECUTING -> EXECUTING_DISCONNECTED
15 03 2019 00:09:50.320:WARN [HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (0 times)reconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (transport close)
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnectedreconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (transport close)
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 12 of 92 DISCONNECTED (4.476 secs / 1.875 secs)
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 12 of 92 DISCONNECTED (4.476 secs / 1.875 secs)
15 03 2019 00:09:50.340:DEBUG [karma-server]: Run complete, exiting.
```

Answer (score 1):

Even with the debug logs there was very little to go on. My last hope was to look into the suspicious

```
[middleware:source-files]: Requesting /assets/img/logo.png
[middleware:source-files]: Requesting /media/img/showcase-image.jpg
```

messages. I had also seen logs such as `WARN [web-server]: 404: /media/img/showcase-image.png` but coming from both local runs and Gitlab CI.

> It was helpful to read [how to fix 404 warnings for images during karma unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067710/how-to-fix-404-warnings-for-images-during-karma-unit-testing?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well as the Karma [files](http://karma-runner.github.io/3.0/config/files.html) docs.

The solution was to fix these 404s and ensure all my 'fictitious' test image urls resolved to **real images**. After which the Gitlab CI task worked properly.

Here's the config I needed to add to *karma.conf.js*:

```
files: [
   {pattern: 'assets/img/*.png', watched: false, included: false, served: true, nocache: false},
   {pattern: 'testing/assets/img/*.png', watched: false, included: false, served: true, nocache: false}
],
proxies: {
   "/assets/": "/base/assets/",
   "/media/": "/base/testing/assets/img/"
},
```

**Explanation**

My Angular app uses images both bundled in the *assets* folder in the Angular project as well as images served from a CMS backend.

The first item in the *files* list configures Karma to load local assets such as *assets/img/logo.png* into the testing browser. Karma serves the loaded assets on the `/base/` url, so `logo.png` could be accessible at `/base/assets/img/logo.png`. The first line in `proxies` proxies a request for `assets/img/logo.png` to `/base/assets/img/logo.png`, thus ensuring the `logo.png` is loaded in the test.

The same idea is true for fake urls supplied for images served by the CMS. I added a 'fake' image in *testing/assets/img/fake.png* in my project.   In this case, my backend would normally serve static files at `/media/` so I was able to update all my tests to supply `/media/fake.png` as the url, which is proxied to `/base/testing/assets/img/fake.png`.

**Example Test**

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.product = {
      // other data here
      image: {
        url: '/media/fake.png'
      }
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
}

it('should display image in card', () => {
    const img = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('img');
    expect(img.src).toEqual('/media/fake.png')
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the img error was the cause of the error? We run into the same issue but the images error in test never caused this problem.

Comment: @elpddev yes my CI pipeline started to work correctly after I implemented these changes to resolve the image urls. Hope you solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same error in an Angular hybrid app once I started importing downgraded Angular 8 services into Angular JS (1.x) services. We were able to resolve the issue by setting the "--js-flags=--max-old-space-size=8196" flag for HeadlessChrome in our *karma.cong.js*

```
    customLaunchers: {
        headlessChrome: {
            base: "ChromeHeadless",
            flags: [
                "--no-sandbox",
                "--js-flags=--max-old-space-size=8196", <<< add this
            ],
        },
    },
```