# Jasmine testing Ionic Icons svg not found

Tags: ionic-framework, jasmine

[image]

When I try to test my Ionic/Angular app with Jasmine it can't seem to find any of the Ionic Icons I used, so it throws a 404 for all of them. All the tests pass but its hard to read since the errors take up quite a lot of space so if one does fail its annoying.

The icon do work in the normal code.

How do I include the SVGs into my tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`, you need to import that module responsible for painting the Ionic Icons.

You can also set up proxies to get rid of those 404 errors as outlined in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58291420/7365461.

Comment: I tried a bunch of those solutions but they didn't work, I've now revisited them and found that my problem was using absolute paths, for some reason it only works if I use relative paths. All fixed now. Thanks!